# Controller not reachable in jquery/ajax with CodeIgniter and bootstrap template

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

So i'm loading a page into another, everything works fine but the controller loading:

I'm loading the scripts and the css in the default page code and this may be the problem, but i can't figure out what it is. It "returns Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

**My View Code:**

```
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css')?>" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="add_etudiant()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Ajouter un étudiant</button>
     <br />
    <br />
    <table id="table_id" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
                    <th>Matricule</th>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>Prénom</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>Date de naissance</th>
                    <th>Action</th>


        </tr>
      </thead>

       <tbody>
                <?php foreach($etudiant as $row){?>
                     <tr>
                         <td><?php echo $row->matricule;?></td>
                         <td><?php echo $row->nom;?></td>
                                 <td><?php echo $row->prenom;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->datenaiss;?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="edit_etudiant(<?php echo $row->matricule;?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_etudiant(<?php echo $row->matricule;?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>


                                </td>
                      </tr>
                     <?php }?>



      </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>




  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js')?>"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#table_id').DataTable();
  } );
    var save_method; //for save method string
    var table;


    function add_etudiant()
    {
      save_method = 'add';
      $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
      $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
    $('.modal-title').text('Ajouter un étudiant'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title
    }


    function save()
    {
      var url;
      if(save_method == 'add')
      {
          url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/etudiant/etudiant_add')?>";
      }
      else
      {
        url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/book/book_update')?>";
      }

       // ajax adding data to database
          $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {
               //if success close modal and reload ajax table
               $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
              location.reload();// for reload a page
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error adding / update data');
            }
        });
    }




   </script>


     <div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Book Form</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body form">
        <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
          <input type="hidden" value="" name="book_id"/>
          <div class="form-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3">Matricule</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="book_isbn" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3">Nom</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="book_title" class="form-control" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3">Prénom</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="book_author" class="form-control" type="text">

              </div>
            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">E-mail</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="book_category" class="form-control" type="text">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Date de naissance</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input name="book_category" class="form-control" type="text">

                            </div>
                        </div>

          </div>
        </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**My Controller Code:**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('etudiant_model');
}

public function index()
{
   $this->data['etudiant']=$this->etudiant_model->get_all_etudiant();

}



public function etudiant_add()
    {
        $data = array(
                'matricule' => $this->input->post('matricule'),
                'nom' => $this->input->post('nom'),
                'prenom' => $this->input->post('prenom'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'datenaiss' => $this->input->post('datenaiss')
            );
        $insert = $this->etudiant_model->etudiant_add($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }


enter code here

public function etudiant_edit($id)
    {
        $data = $this->etudiant_model->get_by_id($id);



        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function etudiant_update()
{
    $data = array(
                'matricule' => $this->input->post('matricule'),
                'nom' => $this->input->post('nom'),
                'prenom' => $this->input->post('prenom'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'datenaiss' => $this->input->post('datenaiss')
            );
    $this->etudiant_model->etudiant_update(array('matricule' => $this->input->post('matricule')), $data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}

public function etudiant_delete($id)
{
    $this->etudiant_model->delete_by_id($id);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}   
}
```

Can you please help me on this because the error message is not clear and I can't figure it out !

Comment: for which resource (js, css) it is showing that message?

Comment: for the jquery:http://localhost/ajax_crud_datatables/index.php/index.php/etudiant/etudiant_add Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: extra ```index.php``` added in your url. Please use ```base_url()``` instead ```site_url()``` in you ajax.

Comment: I did , same error

Comment: Hey, You are writing code in Welcome controller, but in ajax, you gave url of etudiant controller? Can you please check with your code, or update it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove index.php from your config.php base_url (which I assume is where you first index.php is) and test that http://localhost/ajax_crud_datatables/index.php/etudiant/etudiant_add (index.php only once)  is reachable before attempting to make your ajax function work.